# Does halacha allow married couple living under the same roof with parent(s)?

Tags: halacha, marriage

A long time ago I heard a rabbi saying that the halacha forbids married couple living with their parents, not even in the same city.

I want to know if that is true and if someone can provide a source quote.
Toda!

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but I've never heard of this and know of many rabbis who live in the same city as their parents

Comment: One of the theories on the um, sortof-practice not to marry someone with your mother's name is because houses often *did* have multiple generations under one roof, and if you called out "Sally" in the dark in the middle of the night ... so maybe whoever said this meant "if your wife and mother have the same name?" Or maybe someone was simply giving good advice for a lot of folks today who like having more space / boundaries?

Comment: There is no halacha that forbids a couple from living in the same city as their parents. I also know of many young couples who lived for a few years in the basement of one of their parents and no one ever claimed this was against halacha.

Comment: In Europe, it was common for married children to live in the same one-room houses as their parents.

Comment: This is coming from the gemarra in Kiddushin 12b but didn't see the Rishonim or poskim. The city thing is incorrect.

Comment: Tosfos Kiddushin 12b http://www.tosfosinenglish.com/pdf/Kidushin/12b5bekulhoo.pdf

Answer (score -2):

There are some communities that are careful that brothers who are married to sisters should live in separate neighborhoods.

(Rabbi Yehuda Hachasid wrote in his will for these marriages between siblings not to take place. See https://dinonline.org/2016/01/18/2-sisters-marrying-2-brothers/     Living in separate communities seems to be a method of taking care of the concerns of Rabbi Yehuda Hachasid. The father and uncle of the Lubavitch Rebbe were married to two sisters with such a condition. See Igros Kodesh, Vol. III, p. 182, Vol. VI, p. 190, Vol. VIII, p. 31.)

Comment: This does not answer the question.